# how to send large RGB values as parameters to be read as a picture in python

Tags: python, dataframe, opencv, image-processing, imread

I have a data frame called labels which looks like this:

```
name    label
0   [[[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255,...   black
1   [[[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255,...   black
2   [[[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255,...   black
3   [[[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255,...   black
4   [[[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255,...   black
```

and I want to send the name to a function which then views it as an image and then detects the colour. however when I tried writing this code i got an error:

```
predict(labels.name[0])

error:  
     18         names =[]
     19 
---> 20         image = cv2.imread(image_path)
     21         image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
     22         #image_yuv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)

SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more info. For example, what is the value for image_path that you've sent to the imread function? Did you verify the path is pointing to actual data?

Comment: imread is inside the function predict and it takes an image like (img1.jpg) and works fine

Comment: If imread is working fine here, then why it is throwing the SytemError exception? Could you please print image_path and post the same in the question?